# Making an Object accessible in a controllers which was set in kernel.controller Event

Tags: symfony

How can make an Object accessible in a controllers which was set in `kernel.controller` Event?

I have a `onKernelController` method which is run before controller and I need some data in a controller which was set in `onKernelController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dependency injection to solve this:

1) Turn your object/class into a service and inject it into the listener.

```
services:
    your_object:
        class: Your\Namespace\YourObjectClass

    your_listener:
        class: Your\Namespace\YourListener
        arguments: [ @your_object ]
        tags:      
            - { name: kernel.controller, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelController }
```

2) Set some property (can be an object aswell) on the injected object

**listener class**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class YourListener
{
    protected $object;

    public function __construct($object)
    {
         $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // ...

        $object->setProperty('some_property_value');
    }
}
```

3.) Get the property inside a container-aware controller (or turn your controller into a service aswell and inject `@your_object` )

**controller**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
// or: use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SomeController extends ContainerAware // or: extends Controller
{

    public function someAction()
    {
        $property = $this->container->get('your_object')->getProperty; 
        // $property => 'some_property_value'
    }
```

Comment: Should not it be `arguments: [ @your_object ]` instead of `arguments: [ @your_service ]`? What does `@` mean?

Comment: that's correct, i fixed it :) `@your_object` means inject the service `your_object` , while `%some_name%` would inject the parameter `some_name`, and `some_name` would just inject the string `some_name`. clear enough?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Roman - i changed `your_service` to `my_object` to make it more obvious and forgot to change the references aswell :) Happy coding!